# Keyboard flickering issue on TextInput focus with React Native 0.73 and Expo SDK 50

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm experiencing a peculiar issue with TextInput in my React Native app using version 0.73, along with Expo SDK version 50. Whenever I try to enter text into any TextInput field, the keyboard starts flickering or flashing rapidly as long as the input is focused. This behavior is only present in --profile preview apk, since in development mode works ok.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqBvU.png)

Checked for any KeyboardAvoidingView or custom keyboard handling logic that might be causing the issue.
Ensured that the issue persists even in the simplest form of TextInput, without any additional props or styling.
Searched for similar issues among React Native or Expo forums and GitHub issues but haven't found any reported cases with the same symptoms.